# Bouncy Castle: Creating CMS (a.k.a. PKCS7) certificate?

Tags: ssl, cryptography, ssl-certificate, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

How do I create a CMS (a.k.a. PKCS7) certificate?

The following bouncy castle code creates a PKCS12 certificate:

```
    ASN1EncodableVector  v = new ASN1EncodableVector();

    v.add(tbsCert);
    v.add(sigAlgId);
    v.add(new DERBitString(signature));

    X509CertificateObject clientCert = new X509CertificateObject(Certificate.getInstance(new DERSequence(v))); 

    PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier bagCert = clientCert;
    bagCert.setBagAttribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_friendlyName,
            new DERBMPString("Certificate for IPSec WLAN access"));
    bagCert.setBagAttribute(
            PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_localKeyId,
            new SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure(pubKey));
```

I see there is [CMSSignedDataGenerator](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedDataGenerator.html) in the API, but I am not if it's applicable to my case and if so how....

I also don't understand why, if the created certificate is a PKCS12 one, then why do they use PKCS9 variables in order to built it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a CMS certificate or PKCS#12 certificate.

CMS is the cryptographic message syntax. It specifies a container format that may contain X5.09 compatible certificates of the signer. PKCS#12 is a container format for cryptographic objects, it is often used to store one or more certificate/private key pairs. PKCS#9 explicitly defines attributes for X5.09 certificates.

You probably just need to build an [X5.09 certificate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280), possibly using [PKCS#9 defined attributes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2985). Those certificates should be compatible with both CMS and PKCS#12.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the concept. So should I say a CMS type of cryptographic message/container, to load into which my newly created client X5.09 certificate? If so, then practically how do I create such a container format with bouncy castle API...?

Comment: You can try [Beginning Cryptography with Java](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0764596330) "and implement secure Java applications and make use of standard protocols such as CMS" from (one of the) author(s), David. Or check out the sample code. Note that the book is not that new, so you may need to update the code a bit. And yes, that's the general idea :)